# How to Get Nested Children From Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I need to get the nested children (See Photo) from firebase. I would like to show a recyclerview that is only from a particular user. Below is what I have so far, but this is giving me all of the children.

```
DatabaseReference notificationInviteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Strings.InvitesReference);
notificationInviteRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
        ArrayList<Model_Notifications_Invite> model_notification_invites = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot2:snapshot1.getChildren()) {

            Model_Notifications_Invite invites = snapshot2.getValue(Model_Notifications_Invite.class);
                model_notifications_invites.add(invites);

        }
        myNotificationsAdapter.updateNotificationsList(model_notifications_invites);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have two unknown levels in your data structure, which means you need two nested loops in your `onDataChange`: one for each level.

```
DatabaseReference notificationInviteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Strings.InvitesReference);
notificationInviteRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
        ArrayList<Model_Notifications_Invite> model_notification_invites = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot2:snapshot1.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot3:snapshot2.getChildren()) {
                Model_Notifications_Invite invites = snapshot3.getValue(Model_Notifications_Invite.class);
                model_notifications_invites.add(invites);
            }
        }
        myNotificationsAdapter.updateNotificationsList(model_notifications_invites);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); //  never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. One last thing, and my apologies if i wasn't clear in explaining. Do you know how i can get the children that are only from the current user id? The above code, i am getting all of the children, but now i just want only the children where the child has the current user id. Thank you.

Comment: Nvm i figure it out. Thank you for the first part. it was helpful. I did the following:

 
String notificationPath = snapshot3.child("inviteeUserId").getValue(String.class);
                        if(notificationPath.equals(currentUser)){
                            Model_Notifications_Invite invites = snapshot3.getValue(Model_Notifications_Invite.class);
                            model_notifications_invites.add(invites);
                        }